# How can i loop over tables in R with the format YYYYMM

Tags: r, loops

I have 24 tables in SQL work folder that goes with tablenameyearMONTH format that goes from 201304-201502 (i.e. tablename201304 ,tablename201305, tablename201306 this goes like this up to tablename201503 ). I need to put all these tables from SQL into R and put into one master table. All the table names are the same apart from the dates(dates go up by 1 month everytime), i was wondering what the best way to do this

I know how to get the data from SQL using ODBC i'm just struggling with dates in R. How should I loop the data in R so all the table can be put into one single table?

Comment: You'll have to provide to example data, some of the code you've tried (or at least how you'd like to import a single table) and the expected output. Currently its unclear what you are asking to do. If all you want is a way to make a list of all your table names you can use `paste0("tablename",201304:201502)`

Comment: What I would like to do is join all the tables from 201304 up to 201503 and put into one master table! I can do it SAS and SQL but having trouble with R